# How do I loop through the properties of a generic class in c#?

Tags: c#, mongodb, generics

I am working on a web application that prints various computer parts on the user's screen which they can make a choice out of, with the appropriate price and link. I use MongoDB to store the data, and I use a generic class to dynamically choose the appropriate class (each implement IProduct and have unique properties).

Consider this method:

```
public HtmlString DatabaseResult<T>(string collectionName)
    where T : IProduct 
    {
        var collection = db.GetCollection<T>(collectionName);
        var buildString = "";
        var query =
        from Product in collection.AsQueryable<T>()
        where Product.Prijs == 36.49
        orderby Product.Prijs
        select Product;
        PropertyInfo[] properties = typeof(T).GetProperties();
        foreach (T item in query){
            buildString = buildString + "<p>";
            foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
            {
                buildString = buildString + " " + item.property; //Error Here
            }
            buildString = buildString + "</p>";
        }
        HtmlString result = new HtmlString(buildString);
        return result;
    }
```

Where I am trying to loop through the properties of a class that implements IProduct. Each class that does so have 4 properties in common, and 3 properties that differ. This is why I need to programmatically loop through the properties. I realized that using a reflection to use properties on an actual class is not going to work. Here is my error (the error occurs where I commented in the above method)

```
'T' does not contain a definition for 'property' and no extension method 'property' accepting a first argument of type 'T' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

the result should be something like:

```
"<p>" 
+(value of Motherboard.Price) (value of Motherboard.Productname) 
(value of Motherboard.Productlink) value of Motherboard.YetAnotherAttribute).... etc+
"</p>"
```

Is my desired method of doing this even possible? I'm looking for a solution to my problem, even possibly an entire redesign of my code where necessary. Thanks in advance for answering.

Comment: replace `item.property` with `property.GetValue(item,null)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
buildString = buildString + " " + item.property;
```

To

```
buildString = buildString + " " + property.GetValue(item, null).ToString();
//or
buildString = String.Format("{0} {1}", buildString, property.GetValue(item, null));
```

`PropertyInfo.GetValue` doesn't need the second paramater as of .NET 4.5, I believe

Comment: My apologies, I didn't mean to print the literal "item.property" but the actual value of the item.property. such as: Motherboard.Prijs or Coolers.Luchtverplaatsing, and the actual value of those. I will edit my question.

Comment: That's certainly do-able. I use a very similar method for mapping SQL stored procedure results to models. I will update my answer.